# jquery post works but not with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm totally lost, I copied this from my other apache server where this works just great (I get response as json etc...), now I tried this on other apache server and this does not work (the post goes in to server but not as json). If I have 'json' I don't get response (because I have jsonencode in php, but if I just echo result, it will come back, however this javascript will never go to function(r), so it does not ever even alert('test').

When I remove 'json', it works just fine, however I can't have proper response because php handles it and return it in jsonencoded array. This also goes behind function(r) and shows me the results...

There is no javascript error or php errors. I don't even know where to start debugging...

I also tried $.ajax({ equilevant to both methods and same results.

```
$.post('request.php', { getcontent: 'modal' }, function(r) {
  title.html(r.title);
  content.html(r.content);
  footer.html(r.btns);
  $('#modal').modal('show');
  tinymce.remove();
  tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea', plugins: 'link anchor code image fullscreen textcolor colorpicker' });
},'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers to look at:

The last argument is the expected datatype of the response, not of the sending object. Maybe php does not receive the post correctly.

You might want to set an header in php to:
`header('Content-type: application/json');`
To make sure your response is in json.

The url (request.php) of your post might not be reachable

Comment: Thanks, this guide me to right path. Issue was in file encoding, it was iso 8859-1 instead of utf8, so either file must be in utf8 OR encode result like   `exit(
      json_encode(
        array(
          'title' => utf8_encode($title),
          'content' => utf8_encode($html),
          'htmleditor' => utf8_encode($s['content']),
          'btns' => utf8_encode($btns)
        )
      )
    );`
to be honest, this is not first and unfortunately last time encoding causes headache to me. And of course, I didn't check file encodings after moving them to new apache server...

Comment: Glad to help! 
To encode the whole array at once:
`array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
                $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
});`